# How to remove all ¬ marks from word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, documents

Finding and replacing tools don't recognize this mark. I tried to google the answer but couldn't find it and I'm tired of finding them manually and deleting them one by one. If someone can help me I'll be very grateful!

Comment: If the marks disappear (or change to hyphens) when you click on the paragraph-mark button, then the symbol you are looking for is the **optional hyphen**. If they remain unchanged, then you are looking at character 170 in ASCII code page 437, or Unicode character 172 in the LATIN_1_SUPPLEMENT block.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the following basic search settings worked in Word 2016: (I pasted all the marks directly from the title of your question.)

---

[image]

After pressing **Replace All**, the marks are gone.

---

EDIT:

Another possibility is to disable showing optional hyphens in options:

[image]

Yet another possibility is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> if special characters were displayed by toggling this.
If you still have any difficulties, please edit your question and more specific on what is going different from ordinary search/replace
.

Comment: It says that "no results were found" when I try to find or replace ¬. It's one of those hidden marks.

Comment: @Sausagedog: Assuming that the character is an optional hyphen, try typing **^-** (caret+hyphen) in the **Find what** field (or click **Special**, and then select **Optional Hyphen**).

Comment: Thank you all! Hiding the hyphens wasn't enough, my mission was to delete them all. But it was easier to spot them when only optional hyphens were visible, not all these hidden marks. Typing ^- to the searching field finally solved my problem, word recognized that.

Comment: @Sausagedog If this answer solved your issue, consider making it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This character is representing another character in word if you enable "show hidden characters". I'm not entirely sure which character it represents. It could be a tab or a space, or a marker for cells.

Either way, you can simply disable these by pressing the "show hidden characters" button, which looks like this: <kbd>¶</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found a solution in another forum.
You use the kb arrows and keys to copy one letter on each side of the hyphen and then past it into REPLACE and delete the first and last character (leaving the invisible hyphen).
They press "ReplaceAll" and it works!

Comment: a link to the other forum would be helpfull